# Sorting column for day of week?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have df as below:

```
      day     value
    Friday      32
    Friday      32
    Monday      11
    Monday      22
    Saturday    44
    Saturday    25
    Sunday      77
    Sunday      88
    Thursday    88
    Thursday    88
    Tuesday     88
    Tuesday     88
    Wednesday   88
    Wednesday   88
```

How can I sort this in order of correct weekday?

I tried:

```
weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

df.Weekday = pd.Categorical(df.day,categories=weekdays)

df = df.sort_values('day')
```

it runs but does not change output,

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just had a few mistypos:

```
df.Weekday = pd.Categorical(df.day,categories=weekdays)
```

should be:

```
df['Weekday'] = pd.Categorical(df.day,categories=weekdays)
```

and

```
df = df.sort_values('day)
```

should be:

```
df = df.sort_values('Weekday')
```

and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one with `calender` and `reindex`:

```
import calendar
idx=(df['day'].map({v:k for k,v in dict(enumerate(calendar.day_name)).items()})
     .sort_values().index)
df.reindex(idx)
```

---

```
          day  value
2      Monday     11
3      Monday     22
10    Tuesday     88
11    Tuesday     88
12  Wednesday     88
13  Wednesday     88
8    Thursday     88
9    Thursday     88
0      Friday     32
1      Friday     32
4    Saturday     44
5    Saturday     25
6      Sunday     77
7      Sunday     88
```